# Serialization and deserialization of two dimensional float array in C++

Tags: c++, serialization, struct, deserialization

I have a structure:

```
struct Desc {
    int rows;
    int cols;
}
```

and two dimensional float array.

I need to transfer the structure and `data` through the network. How to serialize/deserialize it correctly?

This is what I do now:

```
Desc desc;
desc.rows = 32;
desc.cols = 1024;
float data[rows][cols];
// setting values on array
char buffer[sizeof(Desc)+sizeof(float)*desc.rows*desc.probes];
memcpy(&buffer[0], &desc, sizeof(Desc));    // copying struct into the buffer
memcpy(&buffer[0]+sizeof(Desc), &data, sizeof(float)*rows*probes);    // copying data into the buffer
```

but I'm not sure if this is a correct approach.

Can someone give me some hints how to do this?

Comment: Serialization works different. You must try make a format that you can send over the wire, this typically done by converting them to string. One should not make a binary copy to a char array. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization

Answer (score 1):

If you stay in C++ and want to be efficient I would use [Boost Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) - otherwise JSON might be your friend. I adapted the [demo](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#simplecase) for serializing your struct to a file - but basically it writes/reads to/from streams.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

struct Desc {
    int rows;
    int cols;

    private:

    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & rows;
        ar & cols;
    }

    public:
    Desc()
    {
        rows=0;
        cols=0;
    };

};

int main() {

    std::ofstream ofs("filename");

    // prepare dummy struct
    Desc data;
    data.rows=11;
    data.cols=22;

    // save struct to file
    {
        boost::archive::text_oarchive out_arch(ofs);
        out_arch << data;
        // archive and stream closed when destructors are called
    }

    //...load struct from file
    Desc data2;
    {
        std::ifstream ifs("filename");
        boost::archive::text_iarchive in_arch(ifs);
        in_arch >> data2;
        // archive and stream closed when destructors are called
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note: I've not checked if this example works.

*Jost

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use NOT binary serialization. For example: plain text(std::stringstream), JSON, XML etc.

С++ example:

```
int width = 10;
int height = 20;
float array[height][width];
std::stringstream stream;
stream << width << " " << height << " ";
for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
  {
    stream << array[i][j] << " ";
  }
}

std::string data = stream.str();
// next use the data.data() and data.length()
```